# Sample code for Paypal Adaptive Chained Delayed payment in Python / Django

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to implement the Adaptive Payments API into my marketplace but I'm having a really hard time with the API, IPN etc..

Any chance somebody has some code samples that could help me anyhow?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what code you have written? show us what have you tried?

Comment: I am using django-paypal-adaptive library from GitHub which is OK, but I'm having a hard time understanding the code.

I was thinking that if there were other code samples I could understand it better.